# How do you say «sala de estar» in Brazilian Portuguese?

Tags: gramática, português-brasileiro

> Os meus filhos estão na sala de estar, brincando.

Is there a Brazilian Portuguese version for that word?

Comment: it is the same. However, in spoken language, Brazilian speakers would usually just say "sala".

Comment: @rdllopes It's the same in Portugal.

Comment: @rdllopes please avoid answering in comments.

Comment: @Aneves, my intention was not to answer but just to provide a comment about the spoken language.

Answer (score 8):

Não, no Brasil isso também é «sala de estar».

Trata-se de um local onde recebemos visitas. Ela está sempre muito bem organizada e decorada. O sofá é o móvel imprescindível da sala de estar.

Veja a imagem:

[image: uma sala de estar, com sofá uma mesinha e bibelôs de decoração]
Fonte:http://sofotos.org/fotos-de-salas-decoradas

Existe também uma outra versão da sala de estar que é a "sala de TV". Um local onde ficamos mais à vontade para assistir TV. Na maioria da vezes deixamos a copa ou cozinha para lanchar ou almoçar em frente à TV.

Eis uma sala de TV:

[image: uma sala de tv]
Fonte:http://meninadeatitude.com.br/decoracao/decoracao-de-sala-pequena-fotos-e-ideias/

Comment: Também é costume chamar apenas de "sala".